# C++ memory management when passing shared_ptr to lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr, pass-by-value, reference-counting

Consider the following C++ code:

```
void f(std::function<void()> func) {
    func();
}

void g(std::shared_ptr<MyObject> myObjPtr) {
    myObjPtr->someMethod();
}

void h(std::shared_ptr<MyObject> myObjPtr) {
    f([=](){ g(myObjPtr); });
}
```

Are there any memory leaks?

My understanding is `myObjPtr` is copied into the lamba and has its reference count incremented. Then it's copied into `g()` where the reference count is incremented again. When `g()` is done, the `shared_ptr` has reference count decremented. Then after `func()` is executed in `f()` the `shared_ptr` has reference count decremented again. So I think this code keeps the reference count balanced (two increments and two decrements). However, I'm fairly new to `shared_ptr` and lambdas so my understanding could be incorrect.

Comment: The point of `shared_ptr` (and all smart pointers in fact) is that it doesn't let you leak memory or otherwise cause memory management errors. (`shared_ptr` has a special exception to this rule, cyclic references, but that's not happening here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

Also, if the lambda object is copied (as part of wrapping it in a `std::function<void()>` perhaps), then that will also increment the reference count (and decrement it when the copy is destroyed).